# Prove that we cannot find another linearly independent vector

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a matrix $A$$$\begin{bmatrix}
                    4 & 1 \\
                   -1 & 2 \\
                    \end{bmatrix}
$$

with eigenvalues $ω=3, 3$.

Clearly this is a degenerate case. The eigenvector can be written in the form $1/(2a^2)^{1/2} [ a, -a]$. How can I show that I cannot find another linearly independent vecotr?

My attempt:
Suppose $c_1[a,-a]+c_2[x,y]=0$. $c_1(a)+c_2(x)=0$ and $-c_1(a)+c_2(y)=0$ subtracting them gives $2c_1a+c_2(x-y)=0$. From here, I don't know what to imagine how to show that there isn't any $LI$ vectors aside from the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *eigenvectors* (note that there are infinitely many of them) are the solutions of $Av=\omega v$, that is, solutions of
\begin{cases}
4x_1+x_2=\omega x_1\\
-x_1+2x_2=\omega x_2
\end{cases}
that, in this case, is
\begin{cases}
x_1+x_2=0\\
-x_1-x_2=0
\end{cases}
or, in a different formulation, the vectors belonging to the null space of the matrix $A-3I_2$. Since this matrix has rank $1$, the null space has dimension $1$, which means that a linearly independent set in it can consist of at most one element.

Comment: How can you tell that given the rank and dimension of null space, it can consist at most one element?

Comment: @shinobi20 Do you know the definitions of rank of a matrix and dimension of a vector space? The rank-nullity theorem immediately yields that the dimension of the null space is $2-1=1$

Comment: Oh, yeah, the dimension theorem. Anyways! Thanks for you help!